# DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect - Selected values and auto submit on change

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I have the following code of select form:

```
$this->add([
            'name' => 'username',
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
            'options' => [
                'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
                'target_class' => 'Application\Entity\Player',
                'property' => 'username',
                'is_method' => true,
                'empty_option' => '-- Please select Unsername --',
                'find_method' => [
                    'name' => 'getUsername',
                ],
                'label_generator' => function ($targetEntity) {
                return $targetEntity->getId() ;
            },
        ],
    ]);
```

My questions are:

- Is it posible selected value to display as default?
  (example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)
- Is it possible to do submit when changing position
  Thank in advance for your help

Comment: `Is it posible selected value to display as default?` Yes. If you bind an Entity to the Form and have set the Form hydrator to DoctrineObject, then this is done for you when you populate the Form. (This also happens in a nested sense over nested Fieldset / Collection objects when using them in a Form). Examples see the readme of [my repo](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-form) to help with form handling along with [examples here](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-form-examples).

Comment: `Is it possible to do submit when changing position` - Yes. For this you'll have to use JavaScript client-side. E.g set an EventListener on the Form element rendered client side to listen for `'change'` events. On that change, send it to the server. Server-side, detect it concerns a partial submit with `$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()` in the Controller where you wish to handle this (assuming it extends ZF's `AbstractController`).

Comment: When you've mucked about with this information, and have looked up more, tried different things and bumped into problems, feel free to update your question with your experience at the time or create a new one. In the mean-time, voting to close as "too broad". For the future update and/or new question, please familiarize yourself with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Happy to help after seeing what you come up with.